# How to download an email attachment and store it inside the download folder?

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, servlets

I am creating a java mail application. In that application, if a user clicks the download attachment, the attachment should download and save inside the download folder. In my case the code is working, but I cannot open the downloaded file. It says "Invalid format".

```java
    public ByteArrayInputStream downloadAttachment(Long findtimestamp, String attachment, String type) throws Exception {
            Store store = config.emailConfigration("imap.gmail.com", "Email", "Password");
            Folder[] folders = store.getDefaultFolder().list("*");
            
            if (type.equals("SentMail")) {
                type = "Sent Mail";
            }
            long nextday = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    
            SearchTerm olderthan = new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.LT, new Date(findtimestamp + nextday));
            SearchTerm newerThan = new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.GT, new Date(findtimestamp - nextday));
            SearchTerm andTerm = new AndTerm(olderthan, newerThan);
    
            Message[] arrayMessages = null;
            for (Folder folder : folders) {
                if ((folder.getType() & Folder.READ_ONLY) != 0) {
                    if (folder.getFullName().contains(type)) {
                        folder = store.getFolder(folder.getFullName());
                        folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
                        arrayMessages = folder.search(andTerm);
                    }
                }
            }
    
            for (Message message : arrayMessages) {
                long gettimestamp = message.getSentDate().getTime();
                if (gettimestamp == findtimestamp) {
                    String contentType = message.getContentType();
                    Multipart multiPart = null;
                    if (contentType.contains("multipart")) {
                        multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
                        int numberOfParts = multiPart.getCount();
                        for (int partCount = 0; partCount < numberOfParts; partCount++) {
                            MimeBodyPart part =  (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount);
                            if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
                                String filename = part.getFileName();
                                if (filename.equals(attachment)) {
                                    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                    part.writeTo(outputStream);
                                    return new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
    
            }
            return null;
        }
```

This is the entire class its returning a `ByteArrayInputStream`. Below code will download the attachment.

```java
if (filename.equals(attachment)) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    part.writeTo(outputStream);
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
}
```

I am passing this `ByteArrayInputStream` to this controller.

```java
@GetMapping("/download/{timestamp}/{type}/{attachment}")
private void download(@PathVariable Long timestamp, @PathVariable String type,@PathVariable String attachment, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + attachment);
    ByteArrayInputStream stream = mailservice.downloadAttachment(timestamp, attachment, type);
    IOUtils.copy(stream, response.getOutputStream());
}
```

When I download a .txt file I get this output:

```
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"; name="Omnia Health.txt"
    Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Omnia Health.txt"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
    X-Attachment-Id: f_k63h2zv20
    Content-ID: <f_k63h2zv20>
    
    T01JTkEgQXJhYiBIRUFMVEgNCg0KQSAtIDI2NyBSZWNvcmRzDQpCIC0gMjI0IFJlY29yZHMNCkMg
    LSAxODkgICBSZWNvcmRzDQpEIC0gMTI5CVJlY29yZHMNCkUgLSAxNDEJUmVjb3JkcwkNCkYgLSA5
    OQlSZWNvcmRzDQpHIC0gMTIzCVJlY29yZHMNCkggLSAxOTEJUmVjb3Jkcw0KSSAtIDEwNwlSZWNv
    cmRzDQpKIC0gNzUJUmVjb3Jkcw0KSyAtIDkyCVJlY29yZHMJDQpMIC0gMTA0CVJlY29yZHMNCk0g
    LSAyOTUJUmVjb3Jkcw0KTiAtIDEzOAlSZWNvcmRzDQpPIC0gOTIJUmVjb3Jkcw0KUCAtIDE0MglS
    ZWNvcmRzDQpRIC0gMTMJUmVjb3Jkcw0KUiAtIDk2CVJlY29yZHMNClMgLSAzODgJUmVjb3Jkcw0K
    VCAtIDEzOQlSZWNvcmRzDQpVIC0gNDgJUmVjb3Jkcw0KViAtIDczCVJlY29yZHMNClcgLSA3MwlS
    ZWNvcmRzDQpYIC0gMjMJUmVjb3Jkcw0KWSAtIDIyCVJlY29yZHMNClogLSA1NwlSZWNvcmRzDQoj
    IC0gMTYJUmVjb3Jkcw0KDQpUT1RBTEwgPSAzLDM1NuKArA0K
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: *when i donwload a txt file i got this output* download it how?

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the headers of your output (`Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`), the attachment was base64-encoded. You need to base64-decode it.

Quick test on the shell of what you've posted:

```sh
base64 --decode < question.b64
OMINA Arab HEALTH

A - 267 Records
B - 224 Records
C - 189   Records
D - 129 Records
...
```

If that look like what you expected, use [Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Base64.html) to decode. You will need to first remove the email headers, as these are not base64-encoded. To make it fool-proof, query the email headers and do base64-decoding *only* if the `Content-Transfer-Encoding:` header says it's actually base64-encoded. Email parts may be plain text, base64, or quoted-printable. [MimeUtility](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html) may be helpful here.

Comment: using this method i couldn't be able to download the rar and image files but  its working for the TXT files and doc files

Answer (score 0):

Check this function ... it's working for me.

```
   private static File saveFile(BodyPart bodyPart, String pathFile) throws Exception {

    InputStream is = bodyPart.getInputStream();
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now(Clock.systemUTC());
    SaveFileHelper.createDir(pathFile);

    String fileName = now.toString();
    if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("windows")) // Windows does not accept char ':' as file/folder name
        fileName = fileName.replaceAll(":", "_");
    fileName += bodyPart.getFileName();

    File file = new File(pathFile, fileName);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
        fos.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    fos.close();

    return file;
}
```

I am using like this

```
  if (messages[i].getContent() instanceof Multipart) {

        Multipart multipart = (Multipart) messages[i].getContent();

         for (int j = 0; j < multipart.getCount(); j++) {
        
               BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(j);
               if (!Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(bodyPart.getDisposition()) && StringUtils.isBlank(bodyPart.getFileName())) {
                        continue; // dealing with emailMessages only
                    }

                    File file = saveFile(bodyPart, pathFile);

                    List<File> messageAttachments = new LinkedList<File>() {{
                        add(file);
                    }};

                    emailMessages.add(new EmailMessageDto() {{
                        attachments = messageAttachments;
                        from = messageFrom;
                        sentDate = messageSentDate;
                        subject = messageSubject;
                    }});
                }
            }
```

save filter function ...

```
 public static File saveFile(InputStream is, String path, String fileName) throws Exception {

    OutputStream out = null;
    try {

        File newFile = new File(path, fileName);
        out = new FileOutputStream(newFile);

        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }

        return newFile;

    } catch (Exception e1) {
        throw e1;
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (out != null) {
            try {
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please switch to [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) or at least don't swallow exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using a easiest way i return the entire inputstream instead of converting to ByteArrayInputStream.

```
public InputStream downloadAttachment(Long findtimestamp, String attachment, String type)
            throws Exception {
        Store store = config.emailConfigration("imap.gmail.com", "Email", "Password");
        Folder[] folders = store.getDefaultFolder().list("*");

        if (type.equals("SentMail")) {
            type = "Sent Mail";
        }
        long nextday = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

        SearchTerm olderthan = new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.LT, new Date(findtimestamp + nextday));
        SearchTerm newerThan = new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.GT, new Date(findtimestamp - nextday));
        SearchTerm andTerm = new AndTerm(olderthan, newerThan);

        Message[] arrayMessages = null;
        for (Folder folder : folders) {
            if ((folder.getType() & Folder.READ_ONLY) != 0) {
                // System.out.println(folder.getFullName() + ": " + folder.getMessageCount());
                if (folder.getFullName().contains(type)) {
                    folder = store.getFolder(folder.getFullName());
                    folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
                    arrayMessages = folder.search(andTerm);
                }
            }
        }

        for (Message message : arrayMessages) {
            long gettimestamp = message.getSentDate().getTime();
            if (gettimestamp == findtimestamp) {

                String contentType = message.getContentType();
                Multipart multiPart = null;
                if (contentType.contains("multipart")) {
                    multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
                    int numberOfParts = multiPart.getCount();
                    for (int partCount = 0; partCount < numberOfParts; partCount++) {
                        MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount);
                        if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
                            String filename = part.getFileName();
                            if (filename.equals(attachment)) {

                                 return  part.getInputStream();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        return null;

    }
```

**In the controller**

```
@GetMapping("/download/{timestamp}/{type}/{attachment}")
    private void download(@PathVariable Long timestamp, @PathVariable String type,@PathVariable String attachment, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + attachment);
             
        InputStream stream = mailservice.downloadAttachment(timestamp, attachment, type);
        IOUtils.copyLarge(stream, response.getOutputStream(), response.getBufferSize());
        stream.close();
        
    }
```

This method is working fine but the only thing is the downloading speed is very slow (20KB) is there any way to increase the speed.